# Show error when the page is empty

Tags: php

I've a problem to show an error when there are no rows for that page. I will try to explain my problem:

I use category's for my site I take for example 'Test' and I've a post that is related to that category and his ID is 1. So the link will be

`site.com/c/Test/1` This is working well, he displays the information from `ID=1` Also I used `INNER JOIN` So when I go to what ever category like: `site.com/c/Flow/1` he will display an error like `This post doesn't exist!` Because `ID=1` isn't related to the category called `Flow` I've tried to get this problem solved but with out any result.

```
<?php
// BEGIN OF SHOWING CONTENT PAGE
if (isset($_GET['id']))
{
        $naamID = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['nameID']);
        $id     = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
        $idnext = $id + 1;
        $goo    = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM category INNER JOIN post ON category.name = post.cat WHERE post.cat = '" .$naamID. "'") or die(mysql_error());
        $gnn    = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM post WHERE id= $id ") or die(mysql_error());
        $gnnn   = mysql_fetch_assoc($gnn);
        $gooo   = mysql_fetch_assoc($goo);
        if($gnnn   = mysql_fetch_array($gnn == ''))
        {
        echo 'This post doesnot exist!';
        }
        if($gooo['youtube'])
        {
                $fullurl1 = $gooo['youtube'];
                $videoid1=substr($fullurl1,-11);       
        ?>
                <h1> <?php echo htmlspecialchars($gooo["title"]); ?> </h1><br />
                <p>
                <a href="/editpost.php?id=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($gooo['id']);?>"><i>Edit this post</i></a><br />
                <iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo htmlspecialchars($videoid1);?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe><br />
                </p>
        <?php }if($gooo['pic']){ ?>
                <p>
                <h1><?php echo htmlspecialchars($gooo["title"]); ?></h1><br />
                <a href="/editpost.php?id=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($gooo['id']);?>"><i>Edit this post</i></a><br />
                <img src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($gooo["pic"]);?>" style="max-height: auto; max-width: 600px;"/><br>
                </p>
        <?php }
// END OF SHOWING CONTENT PAGE
} else {?>
```

Comment: `if($gnnn   = mysql_fetch_array($gnn == ''))` what does it means?

Comment: Maybe you meant to say `if ($gnnn == mysql_fetch_array...)`in an attempt to see if they are both set to FALSE?  Why not just say `if ($gnnn === FALSE)` to test if the query came back empty?

Comment: @stvcisco There are no rows existed with that ID and category.  and `if ($gnnn === FALSE)` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should be

```
if($gnnn   = mysql_fetch_array($gnn == ''))
        {
        echo 'This post doesnot exist!';
        }
```

like this

```
if(mysql_num_rows($gnn) == 0)
        {
        echo 'This post doesnot exist!';
        }
```